# Should I save an existing jpeg as a jpeg or as a png if I'm slightly altering it with a graphical overlay?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, png, jpeg

In particular, I'm using ImageMagick to draw a square over the jpeg, with a transparent fill and a pretty thin stroke?

My intuition says that the straight lines of the stroke might appear blurry, but that's less important than maintaining the quality and size of the original image.

Is there anything else that I should take into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

Jpeg is lossy: compresses more but the quality decreases. You should try different levels of compression and comprare the results ( quality and size) against the png version. It may depend a lot on the contents of the image ( some images compress better than others)